# How do you utilize expansion as space on Ubuntu?

Tags: disk-usage

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. It was installed with an ISO image from a USB stick of 6TB. It however produces "Low disk space" error.

`df -h` returns:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3,2G  2,5M  3,2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   39G   30G  7,6G  80% /
tmpfs            16G  110M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   68M  189M  27% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3,2G  4,7M  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p3  437G  395G   43G  91% /media/triott/Windows
```

My main system is Windows 10 so when I run on there with the same USB stick that I installed Ubuntu on attached, I can access the USB stick and edit the files there. But on Ubuntu, the USB stick path is not even listed as shown here
[Files > Other Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03uCe.png)

How do I utilize the USB stick as space, and maybe also solve the "Low disk space" errors in this case? I'm very new to Ubuntu so please excuse if the question is very basic.

UPDATE:
Seems like the only option as Nmath suggested is to re-install Ubuntu; I had no luck when trying to make the USB-stick into portable Ubuntu due to the following error but re-intalling Ubuntu's minimal mode and using the USB stick as storage space seems to solve the problems for now.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So by USB-expansion I meant a USB External Desktop Drive, of 6TB in this case. The installation itself only required 512GB and so I was wondering if there's a way to utilize the rest of the driver. I did some research and it seemed the only way might be to reinstall the whole thing, but if there's other ways without having to reinstall it would be very helpful

Comment: Please edit your question for clarity. The term "usb-expansion" term is unusual here -- it will distract and scare away potential answers. It seems like you perhaps installed Ubuntu to a USB stick, but the term does not make it clear what you did nor how nor why your install does not use the entire stick. Don't answer requests for more information in comments; edit your Question instead. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add space to your root file system from another physical disk unless you've previously set up a RAID or LVM.  You have two options:

**Resize the partition where Ubuntu is installed.** However this is only possible if you have unpartitioned free space adjacent to the partition where Ubuntu is installed. Based on the output of your `df` command, it won't be possible.

**Repartition the hard drive and reinstall Ubuntu**. Repartitioning will erase everything and you'll need to start over. Make a backup of your existing data so you can restore it on the new installation.

Remember when defining your system partitions prior to installing an OS that it is very important to allocate enough space for however you intend to use those partitions. Partitions are rigid and inflexible. If you do not allocate enough space, and you run out of space, your options are limited.